# Scheduling jobs while consuming Kafka messages

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, spring-kafka

I want build a single Spring Boot application which does multiple different tasks concurrently. I did research on the internet but I could not find any way out. Let me get into detail. 
I would like to start jobs in certain intervals for example once a day. I can do it using Spring Quartz. I also would like to listen messages on a dedicated internet address. Messages will come from Apache Kafka platform. Thus, I would like to use Kafka integration for Spring framework. 
Is it applicable practically (listening messages all the time and executing scheduled jobs on time)

Comment: Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, but your edit doesn't help me understand the problem. There is nothing to prevent you from running scheduled jobs and listening to kafka in the same application.

Comment: I asked because if the application listens (runs) all the time,  it can not wake up on scheduled times logically. Using Quartz, the application does not run all the time, just checking for the next interval as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally speaking, this design is fine: a single Spring Boot app can consume Kafka messages while also executing quartz jobs.

But higher level, you should ask *why* these two functions belong in a single app. Is there some inherent relationship between the quartz jobs and Kafka messages being consumed? Are you just combining them solely to limit yourself to one app and save on compute/memory resources?

You should also consider the impacts to scalability. What if you need to increase the rate at which you consume Kafka messages? If you scale your app to get more Kafka consumers, you have to worry about multiple apps now firing your quartz jobs.

So yes, it can be done, but without any more detail it sounds like you should break this design into 2 separate applications: one for Quartz and one for Kafka consuming.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. You satisfied my curiosity. Actually, I was thinking the same thing, splitting the project into 2 smaller projects. However, I have to do that way because my boss wants a single application. I tried to convince him but he did not change his mind. So, I will do as  he requests.